# solving summation problem when the lower limit is a negative integer

Tags: summation

How can I do this problem? I am unsure as to whether I can modify the range of the sum so that i = 1, and n = n+13. Help!

$$\sum_{i=-12}^{n} 2i^{2}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could consider two sum:
$$\sum_{0}^{12} 2i^{2} + 2\sum_{1}^{n} i^{2}$$

That's equals to:
$$\frac{12\cdot 13 \cdot 25}{3} + \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{3}$$

Comment: splitting the some into two is possible? how come?

Comment: @udpcon prove the fact that: if $f(x)=x^{2}$ then $f(-x)=f(x)$. So if you check it , you will understand the proof.

Comment: how did you get the first part of the sum? (12*13*25) / 3

Comment: Consider the second part of the sum and put $12$ on it.

Comment: i understand, thank you!